# Is this the right version to use of the WMD Markdown editor?

Tags: html, xhtml, markdown, wmd, wmd-editor

[This Google code repository called "wmd-new"](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/) seems to be latest and most active version of the WMD Markdown editor. It has recent modification dates.

However, it has a [link](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master) labeled "WMD development on github." That seems to imply that actual development is on GitHub, but then you go to there and the updates are way older.

(There's also a link to Stackoverflow labeled "Stackoverflow uses the current WMD." The code in the wmd-new repository produces an editor that's different from Stackoverflow -- it tries to automatically create list items and it has some bugs that aren't present in the Stackoverflow editor.)

Anyway, is wmd-new on Google code the most up-to-date and active publicly available WMD editor version?

Is there another version that's better?

Thanks!

Comment: The "derobins" version seems the most reliable and stable; there are way too many fragmented versions with all manner of bugs in them. I have a compilation that's working for me right now (including showdown, the Javascript preview); I'll look at posting it online in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wmd-new repository is 'officially' the correct one to use, but it has not been updated in many months and contains several bugs. The other fragmented versions around the web are not much better, but there are two options:

A version by [ChiperSoft](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/wmd). This appears to have fixed most bugs and doesn't do the automatic bullet point insertion etc, bringing it closer the the Stack Overflow version. A few nice additions too, including the ability to right- and center-align text. You may need to modify some parts to remove mentions of ChiperSoft, or any other company-specific things.

I have been working on a copy of the WMD editor for an open source SO clone. I have fixed all the bugs I have found, though I also changed a few things to what I feel are more sensible options. [Details and download available from here](http://codelair.co.uk/2011/markdown-editor-plugin-q2a/) (download the zip and grab the `wmd` folder from it). #3 on the bug list has been fixed but not rolled into the zip file just yet.